# Blender Hair Particles avoid selected vertex group? -SOLVED

Tags: mesh, particles, vertex-groups, hair

I keep adding the Vertex Group "scalp" to the density for my character, but instead of following the Vertex Group, the hair particles stop going around the whole body mesh, but just around the vertex group, through the eyes and face, ect. Can anyone help? Thanks!! 
     File:
[image]

Comment: can you upload your file? blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Yeah, I'll do it now!

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Go into edit mode, then inverse the selection.

Then subtract all those faces from the vertex group.

That should do the trick.

BTW your mesh is inside out so you need to go into edit mode for each mesh, select everything and recalculate normals.

Comment: I'm still having a little trouble with inversing the selection...I'm pressing Tab, Control, and 1, but it just changes the subdivision...sorry! Any way to fix that?

Comment: ctrl + i = is inverse selection. Or manually click it in the 3D view header-->select-->inverse.